# How to use a proxy in python and twisted to get a page

Tags: python, url, proxy, twisted

Is it true that if you have a proxy such as  http://222.126.99.99:8909 that you can access a url from the browser e.g. www.cnn.com as http://222.126.99.99:8909/www.cnn.com.

Is this is true, from twisted can I use the proxy to get a page as follows?

```
iUrl=http://222.126.99.99:8909/www.cnn.com
client.getPage(iUrl,method='GET').addCallback(self.processPage,iUrl).addErrback(self.printError,iUrl)
```

Comment: Err, what's the question? Is it a yes or no? If so, yes.

Comment: So yes?  can use the iUrl wit the proxy to get the page?  Is so...thats great.  The question is will is work.

Comment: It might for static pages, but good luck with submitting forms, etc.

Comment: Dont need forms..just fetching a page

Comment: if the proxy requires a username and password..how do I do modify the URL to use the credentials?

Answer (score 1):

> if the proxy requires a username and password..how do I do modify the URL to use the credentials?

The format is:

```
url = 'http://username:password@host:port/path'
```

Though it is [deprecated](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.1).

Note, [it is not safe to send your username and password over http](http://codebutler.com/firesheep).